# Excel VBA SQL - multiple data sources in tab to do CHARTS

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code in VBA. I have a Excel witch have A column (date), and B,C,D,E. ¿How i can read multiple source data from one Excel to do 4 charts?

The four charts will be:

- Column A and Column B
- Column A and Column C
- Column A and Column D
- Column A and Column E

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Pass_CSV_to_xlsx()
    
  Dim sCSVFullName As String, sWbkFullName As String, sFileRoot As String
  Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
  Dim sTemp As String
  
  ' 1. Get CSV file name
  sCSVFullName = "C:\Users\sergi\Desktop\Python\search_trends.csv"

  ' 2. Open CSV file
  Workbooks.Open sCSVFullName
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  
  ' 3. Save as workbook
  sFileRoot = Left$(sCSVFullName, InStrRev(sCSVFullName, ".") - 1)
  sWbkFullName = sFileRoot & ".xlsx"
  wb.SaveAs sWbkFullName, xlWorkbookDefault
  
  ' 4. Parse file
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
  
  ' 5. Insert and populate chart
  With ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
  
    '' chart type
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    
    '' chart data
    .SetSourceData Source:=ws.UsedRange
    
  End With
  
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Gráfico 1")
        .Width = 750
        .Height = 215
        .Left = 0
    End With
  
    ' 6. Save file
    wb.Save
    
End Sub
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Gráfico 1")
        .Width = 750
        .Height = 215
        .Left = 0
    End With
  
    ' 6. Save file
    wb.Save
    
End Sub
```

Comment: There must be some code missing because `wb` and `ws` are undefined, Where is the SQL ?

Comment: Sorry! I have edited the principal message.

Comment: You say that SQL is involved yet there is nothing in your code that shows that?

Comment: I dont know if i understand you. In "chart data" step i want to do 5 diferent source data, each one for each combination that i show in the principal post.

Comment: There is only 4 combinations in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with a csv file like this

```vb
Col A,Col B,Col C,Col D,Col E
ROW1,2,11,21,31
ROW2,3,12,22,32
ROW3,4,13,23,33
ROW4,5,14,24,34

Sub Pass_CSV_to_xlsx()
    
    Dim sCSVFullName As String, sWbkFullName As String, sFileRoot As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    ' 1. Get CSV file name
    sCSVFullName = "search_trends.csv"
    
    ' 2. Open CSV file
    Workbooks.Open sCSVFullName
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
      
    ' 3. Save as workbook
    sFileRoot = Left$(sCSVFullName, InStrRev(sCSVFullName, ".") - 1)
    sWbkFullName = sFileRoot & ".xlsx"
    wb.SaveAs sWbkFullName, xlWorkbookDefault
      
    ' 4. Parse file
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
      
    ' 5. Insert and populate chart
    Dim n As Long, rng As Range
    For n = 1 To 4
        With ws.UsedRange
            Set rng = Application.Union(.Columns(1), .Columns(n + 1))
        End With
        
        With ws.Shapes.AddChart(, Left:=200, Top:=10 + (n - 1) * 160, Width:=500, Height:=150).Chart
            .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
            .SetSourceData Source:=rng
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Chart " & n
        End With
    Next
  
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Gráfico 1")
        .Width = 750
        .Height = 215
       .Left = 0
    End With
  
    ' 6. Save file
    wb.Save
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! That goes well. Thank you! The last thing is about to change tha name of the object in general. Before i  had (.Parent.Name = "MATIC") to 1 chart, but with 5 charts each time i execute the code change the name. 1st time: Chart1, Chart2, Chart3, Chart4 / 2nd Time: Chart5, Chart6, Chart7, Chart8 /etc...

Comment: @sergio If you are running the sub multiple times add a parameter like `Sub Pass_CSV_to_xlsx(i as Long)` and use `.Parent.Name = "Chart" & i*4 + n`. Use i=0 for first run and then increment i for each run.

Comment: Yess! That function well. TY all!